# How to export Collada files in blender

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, collada

Hey i have created an underground tunnel in blender and i want to export it in collada format in blender for using it in my scenekit project but when i export collada file in blender it losses all textures and lights materials which i rendered in blender .You can see in this image i rendered in blender[image: blender format]
After exporting to collada format it looks like this[image: collada format]
Can some one explain how to export collada files which should be completely like original blender rendered....thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can select how textures should be exported in the "Export COLLADA" options usually on the left hand side of the file browser after you pressed *File -> Export -> Collada*. The Texture export options are deactivated by default.

[image: Dialog of texture export options]

Comment: i select option include UV textures but all of the textures are not exported

Comment: How can i export my lights too in collada format

Comment: @Moon - if you have additional questions, please edit your initial question and do not post them in the comments.